# Iphone sdk displaying thumbnail

Tags: iphone

I am trying to acquire a thumbnail (of the first frame) from a video so i can display it. Anyone been succesful at doing this? If so howd you do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are number of methods first one is using AssetImageGenerator:-

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromVideoURL 
{
// result 
UIImage *image = nil;

// AVAssetImageGenerator
AVAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:appDelegate.videoURL options:nil];; 
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

// calc midpoint time of video
Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([asset duration]);
CMTime midpoint = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds/2.0, 600); 

// get the image from 
NSError *error = nil; 
CMTime actualTime;
CGImageRef halfWayImage = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:midpoint actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];

if (halfWayImage != NULL) 
{
    // cgimage to uiimage
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:halfWayImage];
    [dic setValue:image forKey:kImage];
    NSLog(@"Values of dictonary==>%@", dic);
    NSLog(@"Videos Are:%@",appDelegate.videoURLArray);
    CGImageRelease(halfWayImage);
}
return image;
}
```

This is the best method another method is using MPMoviePlayerController:-

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
[player stop];
```

It may help u thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should have videoURL or nsdata of video. Now add MediaPlayer framework and #import MediaPlayer/MPMoviePlayerController.h. add this where you want thumbail of video

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
//Player autoplays audio on init
[player stop];
[player release];
```